# Node json-schema prevent null for interger

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jsonschema

I have schema,

```
'demand': {
    description: 'demand model',
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
        '_id': {
            type: 'string'
        },
        'driversNeeded': {
            required: true,
            type: 'integer',
            minumum: 0
        },
        'date': {
            required: true,
            type: 'string',
            pattern: /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/
        }
    }
}
```

`driversNeeded` is supposed to be integer, with minimum value = 0;

But, then I validate payload `{driversNeeded: null, date: '2015-11-11'}` it treat it as valid.

I except `null` could be only accepted if I explicitly say `["integer", "null"]` in type.

How can I prevent `null` to be accepted as integer?

Comment: FYI, you've also mis-spelled "minimum" in your schema.

Answer (score 1):

That schema works for me, as it should (I get "Invalid type: null (expected integer)").

My best guess is that the issue might be in the larger document structure, meaning that the data isn't actually being tested against the schema you expect.

Comment: Tnx  for answer, I'm pretty sure it's correct.. but will double check again.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work for me. @cloudfeet, can you please let me know with version of json-schema are you trying on?